# Broswers asking consistently for reCAPTCHA in an office network

Tags: networking

This week we started noticing that most of the websites we use in the office ask for a reCAPTCHA validation. This is wouldn't be much of a problem for us, but while testing our website in incognito, the site doesn't load and the console throws [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl1Ex.png). When we visit one of the urls shown in the logs we are greeted again [with another reCAPTHCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1sjb.png). After we pass the validation our site loads fine without any errors. This leads us to think, that there is probably something going on with our network, because this validation pops up on most of the sites we use in incognito: [cloudflare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ovVb.png), [prntscr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIuDb.png) and others. A couple of things I should note:

- This happens on all computers in our network in Edge, Firefox and Chrome.
- Happens constantly in incognito, and in normal browser instances with freshly cleaned cache.
- We see no errors while accessing our site from phones and tablets connected to the same network. (These scripts load on the mobile version of the site too.)

Comment: Out of incognito mode, are you logged into Google? I've read somewhere before that ReCaptcha also looks at your Google account if you're signed in with one.

Comment: @MoonRunestar Yes, out of incognito I'm logged in at least one of my Google accounts. Does it show reCAPTCHA to those who aren't logged, or how exactly does it work with logged in Google accounts?

Comment: Check Nate's answer below.

Comment: For some weird reason, using private browsing on firefox makes reCAPTCHA not work anymore on my machine. Always been like that. Might be related (?). Possibly has to do something with cookies (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the above answer a bit: Google's new reCAPTCHA actually tracks *you* across the Internet, and hides reCAPTCHA if its algorithms determine that your Internet usage history pattern looks more like a human than a bot. Then, once you've completed a reCAPTHCA successfully, it saves a cookie and continues to track you across the Internet. Thus, when you're in incognito mode, because the browser can't track you, you'll thus see the reCAPTCHA message every time you load a page with Google's reCAPTCHA running on it.

Comment: That makes sense. So it's not a problem with our network then. That might also explain why phones have no problem opening the mobile version of the site?